# clipping a part of a plot in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've started learning tikz for about a week now, and I want to make something like this:
[image]

right now I have:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin = 5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amsfonts,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{width=5cm,compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{myaxis}=[xlabel=$x$,
                    ylabel=$y$,
                   xmin=-1, xmax=5,
                   ymin=-1, ymax=5,
                   minor tick num=1,
                   grid=both]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[name=domain,grid=both,
                 xmin=-1,xmax=6,
                 ymin=-1,ymax=5,
                 axis lines=middle,
                 scale only axis,
                 inner axis line style={=>},
                 minor tick num=3,
                 minor grid style={dotted,very thin}]
                 
         \addplot[black,smooth cycle, tension = 1] coordinates{(1,3)(2.5,2.5)(3,1)(4,2)(3,4.5)};
        \begin{scope}
             \clip (1,1) -- (2,3.5) -- (3.5,2.5) -- (2,1) --cycle;
             \addplot[line width=5pt,yellow,smooth cycle, tension = 1] coordinates{(1,3)(2.5,2.5)(3,1)(4,2)(3,4.5)};
        \end{scope}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

my problem is this: since I want to clip a part of a curve and then add a yellow marker around it I can't just clip it with a polygon. any suggestions?
edit: in my solution you can clearly see the edges and I would like to round the yellow curve at the edge a little.

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is, do you want the black line to remain visible in the yellow part? In that case you can probably just replot the line segment after the yellow plot, so add another `\addplot[smooth cycle, tension = 1] coordinates{(1,3)(2.5,2.5)(3,1)(4,2)(3,4.5)};` at the end before `\end{scope}`. Or do you want something different?

Comment: Alternatively, to reduce redundancy, you can first plot the scope and afterwards the normal plot.

Comment: You can also use `\usetikzpackage{backgrounds}` to plot the clipped data in the background or decrease the opacity of the yellow line ...

Comment: my problem is the that the yellow curve isn't smooth, i want it to be round,

Comment: You're not limited to polygons for clipping paths, so something like `\clip [rotate around={-30:(2.5, 2.5)}] (2.3,2.3) circle[x radius=0.7, y radius=0.5];` also works. A bit smoother at least.